# Asp.net application with more than 1 worker process

Tags: asp.net

In IIS application pool I have set 2 in maximum worker process in process model, will application object, session object and cache object will be shared by the all worker process or will all worker process have different application object, session object and cache object.

Comment: It may or may not be relevant, but why do you want two different processes?

Answer (score 2):

If you use in proc state management the session is kept in the running process. So if you have 2 or more workers processes your session will only work by chance. You can use SQL state management or State server. 
Using a state server is pretty fast but if the stateserver fails or reboots all sessions will be lost. Using SQL server is somewhat slower but it has the benefit that the session will be all there after a reboot or any kind of interruption. So what to choose depends on your requirements. If you're running a e-comerce site or similar you could set up the sql server with clustering and multiple webservers to get a better uptime.

As for caching it is the same, the cache is kept in the worker process. Depending of how expensive it is build up objects in the cache you could use MemCached or something like it. But then you need to serialize/deseriliaze the cache objects and send them over the wire to another server, which could be quite expensive as well.